# Defining the multiplication of distributions in the context of QFT : Colombeau algebra vs Regularity structure?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, schwartz-distributions

This is a bit of a qualitative question.

A rigorous treatment of QFT comes down to making sense of multiplication of distributions, as far as I understand. This is in the aim of constructing and manipulating with the interacting field operators after all.

For this purpose, I am under the impression that the theory of regularity structure is regarded as a powerful tool these days.

However, the approach by means of the Colombeau algebra does not seem as popular, though it seems more general in nature.

Could anyone please explain the reason for this?

I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: I believe some of the shortcomings of the theory are commented on here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Colombeau+algebra

Answer (score 7):

For free fields [Colombeau algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra) is equivalent to [normal ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order) (Wick ordering) of products of creation and annilation operators. The latter is more easily described, which may explain the reduced popularity of Colombeau algebra.

Comment: In what sense are they equivalent? Normal ordering applies for the free field operators on a Fock space, as far as I know,

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought that normal ordering the $\phi^4$ interaction gives the same result as in Colombeau algebra.

Comment: In which spacetime dimensions? For the$\phi^4$ theory, it is a very crucial factor..

Comment: I'm only familiar with $d=2$, when normal ordering removes the singularities. If Colombeau is applicable also for $d=3$ then, indeed, it is stronger than Wick. In any case my "equivalent" statement was too strong, I will change that, thanks for your feedback.